# Which Gentoo Package provides Qt5CompositorConfig.cmake?

Tags: compiling, dependencies, qt, sabayon

I would like to compile and then install [Hawaii](http://hawaii-desktop.github.io/) from source code, but I am stuck at the compiling [GreenIsland](https://github.com/greenisland/greenisland) (a dependency of Hawaii) from source code stage. I created a build subdirectory of the source code directory with `mkdir build` and ran:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
```

but this gave the error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Compositor"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5CompositorConfig.cmake
    qt5compositor-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Compositor" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Compositor_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Compositor" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:60 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fusion809/Programs/Hawaii/greenisland-0.6.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

[here](http://pastebin.com/suGdNKkE) is my log file (/home/fusion809/Programs/Hawaii/greenisland-0.6.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log).

I interpret this error to mean I am missing Qt5CompositorConfig.cmake from my system. What Portage ebuild do I need to merge to get this library? If relevant I am working on Sabayon Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, I had [dev-qt/qtwayland](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-qt/qtwayland) installed, but I needed the wayland-compositor USE flag enabled in order to get this library. Once I did that I managed to finish compiling Green Island.